# javascript object literals using it's own fields

Tags: javascript, object, static, literals

I would like to create ONE object containing the whole config for certain component. I would liek it too be like this:

```
var ObjectConfig = {
    fieldKeys : {
        name: "Obj. name",
        state: "Obj. state",
        color: "Obj. color"
    },
    templates : {
        basicTemplate :  [ ObjectConfig.fieldKeys.name, ObjectConfig.fieldKeys.state ],
        altTemplate : [ ObjectConfig.fieldKeys.name, ObjectConfig.fieldKeys.color ]
    }
}
```

But this in the right way to do it - it doesn't work. How can I achieve my goal?

EDIT:
Sorry, I was writing it by hand in a hurry, that's where the syntax errors came from. Now it's correct. The error I get is `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fieldKeys' of undefined`. I guess that doing it this way is impossible - what is the best alternative then?

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. Use `:` instead of `=` to define object properties

Comment: + you skipped comma after `"Obj. state"`.

Comment: + if you mean referencing to properties in the object itself by `it's own fields`, that can't be done

Comment: Sorry, I was writing it by hand in a hurry, that's where the syntax errors came from. Now it's correct. Could you please reevaluate my question?

Comment: any error message on the console?

Comment: I can't find the duplicate, so I'm gonna write an answer :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-references in object literal declarations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616202/self-references-in-object-literal-declarations)

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks, that's what I've looked for. Which search terms did you use?

Comment: @Bergi: [`[javascript] object self reference`](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+object+self+reference)... my answer might not be the best one, but there are a couple of other duplicates as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the object is constructed from the literal *before* it is assigned to the `ObjectConfig` variable. Therefore, accessing `ObjectConfig.fieldKeys` inside the literal will lead to the error.

The best solution is to construct first one object only, and then add further properties sequentially:

```
var ObjectConfig = {
    fieldKeys: {
        name: "Obj. name",
        state: "Obj. state",
        color: "Obj. color"
    }
};
ObjectConfig.templates = {
    basicTemplate:  [ ObjectConfig.fieldKeys.name, ObjectConfig.fieldKeys.state ],
    altTemplate: [ ObjectConfig.fieldKeys.name, ObjectConfig.fieldKeys.color ]
};
```

Another (shorter) method would an extra variable for the keys object, which is assigned before the construction of the templates object:

```
var keys, ObjectConfig = {
    fieldKeys: keys = {
        name: "Obj. name",
        state: "Obj. state",
        color: "Obj. color"
    },
    templates: {
        basicTemplate: [ keys.name, keys.state ],
        altTemplate: [ keys.name, keys.color ]
    }
};
```

To work around the extra variable in global scope, you might use an [IEFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/). A more readable solution might look like this then:

```
var ObjectConfig = (function() {
    var keys = {
        name: "Obj. name",
        state: "Obj. state",
        color: "Obj. color"
    };
    return {
        fieldKeys: keys,
        templates: {
            basicTemplate: [ keys.name, keys.state ],
            altTemplate: [ keys.name, keys.color ]
        }
    };
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer!